# Errors were encountered while processing: jitsi-meet-tokens

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I've been using Ubuntu for a few years now, but I just installed Version 16.04, and I've been having a lot of issues. I'm not a command line expert, but I tried to install some software last night, and it is creating issues (and also not working properly).

When I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, I see the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  lua-event lua-expat lua-filesystem lua-sec lua-socket lua5.1 prosody
Suggested packages:
  lua-zlib lua-dbi-postgresql lua-dbi-mysql lua-dbi-sqlite3
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jitsi-meet-tokens
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lua-event lua-expat lua-filesystem lua-sec lua-socket lua5.1 prosody
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 1 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/413 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,296 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 176266 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jitsi-meet-tokens (1.0.962-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-tokens (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-tokens
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to get this resolved? I'm fine with deleting jitsi, but I'm not sure if that will correct the problem.

Currently there is a red circle with a line through it in the upper right corner that indicates there may be installed packages with unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

If nothing else works, try this. First, back up your status file:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status_bk
```

Open the current status file using your favourite text editor

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Find and remove all of the text about the package you want to remove, in this case:

```
Package: jitsi-meet-tokens
Status: deinstall ok half-installed
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 53
Maintainer: Jitsi Team <dev@jitsi.org>
Architecture: all
Source: jitsi-meet
Version: 1.0.1073-1
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, prosody-trunk (>= 1nightly607), libssl-dev, luarocks, jitsi-meet-prosody
Description: Prosody token authentication plugin for Jitsi Meet
Homepage: https://jitsi.org/meet
```

Save, exit, and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Source: [Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=233205)

Comment: Since this may actually be a useful answer, I have edited it instead of flagging, but please do not uncritically copy and paste information from elsewhere. At the very least, adapt so that it is on topic (Linux Mint is *not* on topic here)

Answer (score 1):

You have a corrupted installation of jitsi. We could go through an analysis to establish what went wrong, but as you are content to remove jitsi it is simpler just to remove it and tidy up your repository.

```
sudo apt-get purge jitsi*
sudu apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I would actually be interested to fix Jitsi, because my plan was to try to reinstall it. However, when I tried your suggestion using  "sudo apt-get purge jitsi," I see the following output:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jitsi-meet-prosody : Depends: prosody or
                               prosody-trunk but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I have updated the answer to deal with this